# How to bind date from API to ng-bootstrap Datepicker in formGroup

Tags: angular, ngb-datepicker

Please find my issue below.

I'm using Angular 5 formGroup and ngbDatepicker for date input. Date picker is working for new form, Please let me know how to bind the date to the date picker through formGroup & formControlName.

Version of Angular and Bootstrap:
Angular: 5
Bootstrap: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only you need is that the input of ngbDatePicker was type of NgbDateStruct, that's is an Object with day,month and year properties

```
this.dataForm = this.fb.group({
     "fecha":[{year:2018,month:1,day:21}]
})
```

Comment: I have created sample code in stackblitz, please check it so you have better understanding what I'm looking for https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngbootstrap-datepicker?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html

Comment: datepicker2: {year:parseInt(apiYear),month:parseInt(apiMonth),day:parseInt(apiDay)}

Comment: and <pre>Model: {{ myForm?.value | json }}</pre>

Comment: Yes worked perfectly!. @Eliseo Thanks for your time and response.